# How to disable Tamper Protection on Windows 10 1709, 1803, or 1809?

Tags: windows-10, group-policy, windows-defender

According to [the documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/microsoft-defender-antivirus/prevent-changes-to-security-settings-with-tamper-protection#are-you-using-windows-os-1709-1803-or-1809):

> If you are using Windows 10 OS 1709, 1803, or 1809, you won't see Tamper Protection in the Windows Security app. In this case, you can use PowerShell to determine whether tamper protection is enabled.

But it does not say how to disable it using PowerShell or a GPO. In fact, Microsoft says they won't add a GPO to disable Tamper Protection. Is Intune the only option to disable Tamper Protection on those versions of Windows 10?

Answer (score 1):

You can go to the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Features` registry key, then Set `TamperProtection`  DWORD value to `0` for turning Off and `5` to on.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need Intune or SCCM, but you do need another app with TI rights, so we can modify relevant OS internals: [Nirsoft - AdvancedRun](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/advanced_run.html)

1 major downside is you will temporarily have no protection during several reboots, but this is only method I found that works.

---

Run this in CMD - Admin:

```
sc.exe qc windefend | findstr BINARY_PATH_NAME
```

Save output in txt file so we can restore that path later.

`%windir%\script-ps` with contents:

```
Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $true
Get-Service WinDefend | Set-Service -StartupType Disabled
Get-Service Sense | Set-Service -StartupType Disabled
Get-Service mpssvc | Set-Service -StartupType Disabled
Get-Service WdNisSvc | Set-Service -StartupType Disabled
sc.exe config WinDefend binPath=%windir%\bfsvc.exe
```

`TamperProtection.cfg` with contents:

```
[General]
EXEFilename=
CommandLine=(gc script-ps) | iex
StartDirectory=%windir%
WaitProcess=0
PriorityClass=32
WindowState=0
UseWindowPosition=0
WindowPosition=20,20
UseWindowSize=0
WindowSize=640,400
RunAs=8
RunAsProcessName=
EnvironmentVariablesMode=1
OSCompatMode=0
UseSearchPath=0
ParseVarCommandLine=1
UseAffinityMask=0
AffinityMask=0 1
Compat640480=0
CompatDisableVisualThemes=0
CompatDisableDesktopComp=0
CompatDisableFullScreenOpt=0
CompatHighDPI=0
CompatColors=0
RunAsUserName=
RunAsDomain=
RunFromService=0
ComputerName=
RunMode=4
ShellExecuteAction=
CommandWindowMode=2
[EnvironmentVariables]
Lines=0
WinPos=2C 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 65 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 9A 03 00 00 A0 02 00 00
```

Now run this in CMD - Admin:

```
AdvancedRun.exe /Run TamperProtection.cfg
```

Hidden PS window runs & execs cmds (not script so no need to bypass PS restrictions) in `%windir%\script-ps` with TI rights. Reboot after run, & now:

`%windir%\script-ps` with contents:

```
reg.exe add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Features" /v TamperProtection /t REG_DWORD /d 4 /f
reg.exe add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Features" /v TamperProtectionSource /t REG_DWORD /d 2 /f
reg.exe add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Features" /v SenseDevMode /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

Now run this in CMD - Admin:

```
AdvancedRun.exe /Run TamperProtection.cfg
```

Reboot after run, & now:

`%windir%\script-ps` with contents:

```
sc.exe config WinDefend binPath=<original BINARY_PATH_NAME>
Get-Service WinDefend | Set-Service -StartupType Automatic
Set-MpPreference -EnableRealtimeMonitoring $true
Get-Service Sense | Set-Service -StartupType Automatic
Get-Service mpssvc | Set-Service -StartupType Automatic
Get-Service WdNisSvc | Set-Service -StartupType Automatic
```

Now run this in CMD - Admin:

```
AdvancedRun.exe /Run TamperProtection.cfg
```

Reboot after run, & Now TamperProtection is disabled, with WinDefend running.

*Note* : To re-enable, set TamperProtection to 5 & reboot. See this other Answer for enable:

[Enable Windows Defender Tamper Protection](https://superuser.com/a/1767746/1770880)

---

Verified on Win11 Enterprise 22H2 default install

While this works for now, it might not in future if M$ patches this "Answer".

Comment: @wasif If TamperProtection is already On, setting TamperProtection to 0 does not work on Win11, perhaps it did historically on Win10.

Comment: This other Answer:
`https://serverfault.com/a/1122382/217221`
was used to disable AV completely, so that it doesn't see reg keys changed while running. Then when it starts again after reboot, it sees reg keys indicating TamperProtection was disabled via GUI & acts accordingly. M$ lies about reg key values for disabling, these values above are only ones I verified that work.

Comment: This didn't work on my Build 23451 prerelease 230428-1438 dev build.  But it did help.  The reg keys didn't have admin permissions to edit.  I used the sc.exe qc windefend to rename the directory in safemode cli.  Then I was able to boot, and use AdvancedRun to change the registry keys in a powershell run as SYSTEM.  That finally got it disabled.  Then I renamed it back in safemode again, as well as added administrator permissions for the reg key and folder via cli.