# Enable Windows Defender Tamper Protection using PowerShell or C#

Tags: powershell, permissions, windows-registry, c#, windows-defender

I understand completely that it's not possible to disable tamper protection programmatically, as this would defeat the point. Though, seeing as it's possible with an InTune or Endpoint license, then it obviously is possible somehow (Microsoft backdoor?).

The thing is, I do not want to disable Tamper Protection for Windows Defender, I only want the ability to enable it programmatically. I thought this 'positive action' would be possible.

```
Set-ItemProperty -LiteralPath 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Features' -Name TamperProtection -Value ([int] 5)
```

First I tried from an elevated console and got `access is not allowed` (I didn't expect this to work):

[image]

Then I tried while running an elevated console as `nt authority\system`, and got `unauthorized operation`:

[image]

Yet according to the permissions window on the `Features` Windows Defender key, `SYSTEM` has `Full Control`?

[image]

Why is this not working, is there a workaround? I can apply a C# or PowerShell solution. The programmatic solution will always be executed locally in the context of the SYSTEM account.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can script disable & enable & re-enable. See my other Answer for disable, which uses same methods as enable, just more steps to disable:

[How to disable Tamper Protection](https://superuser.com/a/1767740/1770880)

You need TI rights to modify that reg key, somehow System rights alone are not enough. While I'm sure there are C# calls you can make in PowerShell for TI rights, let's use an app that can do this already:

[Nirsoft - AdvancedRun](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/advanced_run.html)

`%windir%\script-ps` with contents:

```
reg.exe add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Features" /v TamperProtection /t REG_DWORD /d 5 /f
```

`TamperProtection.cfg` with contents:

```
[General]
EXEFilename=
CommandLine=(gc script-ps) | iex
StartDirectory=%windir%
WaitProcess=0
PriorityClass=32
WindowState=0
UseWindowPosition=0
WindowPosition=20,20
UseWindowSize=0
WindowSize=640,400
RunAs=8
RunAsProcessName=
EnvironmentVariablesMode=1
OSCompatMode=0
UseSearchPath=0
ParseVarCommandLine=1
UseAffinityMask=0
AffinityMask=0 1
Compat640480=0
CompatDisableVisualThemes=0
CompatDisableDesktopComp=0
CompatDisableFullScreenOpt=0
CompatHighDPI=0
CompatColors=0
RunAsUserName=
RunAsDomain=
RunFromService=0
ComputerName=
RunMode=4
ShellExecuteAction=
CommandWindowMode=2
[EnvironmentVariables]
Lines=0
WinPos=2C 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 65 00 00 00 18 00 00 00 9A 03 00 00 A0 02 00 00
```

Now run this in CMD - Admin:

```
AdvancedRun.exe /Run TamperProtection.cfg
```

Reboot after run, & Now TamperProtection is enabled.

Verified on Win11 Enterprise 22H2 default install

While this works for now, it might not in future if M$ patches this "Answer".