# Disable Or enable Tamper Protection using start windowsdefender: scheme

Tags: powershell, security, batch, windows-defender

I recently read [you can enable real time protection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75807224/21956786) by using:

```
start windowsdefender://enablertp/
```

I want to enable/disable Tamper Protection from a batch script using the same concept.

I've tried several things like:

```
start windowsdefender://enabletp/
```

and

```
start windowsdefender://enablerttp/
```

to no avail. I see no actual documentation on what the schemes are. I need to programmatically disable tamper protection for the user so the PowerShell command here always works:

```
Set-MpPreference -Force -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $true
```

Comment: `windowsdefender://enablertp/` just brings up the a Settings screen. You already listed the PowerShell command that enables protection. What's the problem?

Comment: @harrymc it doesn't work unless real time protection is already disabled. I am wondering if there is something similar to do with tamper protection

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable Tamper Protection on Windows 10 1709, 1803, or 1809?](https://superuser.com/questions/1585167/how-to-disable-tamper-protection-on-windows-10-1709-1803-or-1809)

Comment: @harrymc no this disables for good windows defender in general. I want to dynamically enable or disable realtime protection.

Comment: @harrymc I cannot rely on 3d party executable libraries due to copyright issues. I have to have a builtin way to disable realtime protection by disabling tamper protection first. I saw that if you ran the program as SYSTEM it could bypass the security but there is no builtin way of doing it

Comment: That post states that to disable Tamper Protection not from Settings requires very high permissions and there is no way around it. Microsoft values highly this protection, so it places these restrictions.

Comment: I am fairly sure that March 2023 is around the time Microsoft changed the rules on ms-settings URL scheme.  In other words they changed it so it cannot in the same way it could be used prior to that.

Comment: @Ramhound I tested it today with realtime protection today running the latest windows 10. It works after a prompt

Comment: @Ramhound the Realtime protection works with prompt not the Tamper Protection I cannot find documentation on how to programmatically disable it period

Comment: If the only way it works is to use an app, then thats what you have to do.